# Doubt about performance overhead and downside on multicolumns UNIQUE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am building a table in Postgres as specified below

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "ext_id" INTEGER REFERENCES ext_table (ext_id),
  "user_id" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "user_type" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "event_type" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "status" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  "updated_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
  CONSTRAINT "check_valid_user_type" CHECK ("user_type" IN ('TYPE_A', 'TYPE_B')),
  CONSTRAINT "check_valid_event_type" CHECK ("event_type" IN ('EVENT_A', 'EVENT_B', 'EVENT_C')),
  CONSTRAINT "check_valid_notification_status" CHECK ("status" IN ('STATUS_A', 'STATUS_B', 'STATUS_C')),
  CONSTRAINT "no_duplicates" UNIQUE (ext_id, user_id, user_type, event_type)
);
```

In particular, my main concern is related to the `no_duplicates` constraint which, as far as I understood, builds an UNIQUE index under the hood. (Please correct me If I misunderstood).
What I'd like to know are eventual performance overhead or downsides I don't know in building such kind of index with such multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will make data modification slower, like any other index. But if you need that constraint to hold, you have to pay the price for it. In a way, it is like the primary key. That also slows down data modifications, but you still don't question it because you need a primary key for each table.